# Python Matplotlib : Just the graph image

Tags: python, matplotlib

I cannot get [pyplot](http://matplotlib.org/users/transforms_tutorial.html) to produce "cropped" images, that is, get rid of the grey left and right borders, as it is, it is not an accurate representation of the sound waveform : This sound file has no silence before and after.

[image]

My code :

```
import gtk

from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from numpy import arange, sin, pi
import scipy.io.wavfile as wavfile

from matplotlib.backends.backend_gtkagg import FigureCanvasGTKAgg as FigureCanvas

    win = gtk.Window()
    win.connect("destroy", lambda x: gtk.main_quit())
    win.set_default_size(400,300)
    win.set_title("Cropping figure")

    rate, data = wavfile.read(open('/home/px/gare_du_nord-catchlak.wav', 'r'))
    f = Figure()
    a = f.add_subplot(111, axisbg=(0.1843, 0.3098, 0.3098))
    a.plot(range(len(data)),data, color="OrangeRed",  linewidth=0.5, linestyle="-")
    a.axis('off')
    a.autoscale_view('tight')
    canvas = FigureCanvas(f)  # a gtk.DrawingArea

    win.add(canvas)

    win.show_all()
    gtk.main()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, I got [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8182124/how-do-i-autosize-text-in-matplotlib-python/8188287?noredirect=1#comment26699981_8188287) :

```
f.subplots_adjust(0, 0, 1, 1)
```

EDIT:

This also works, in fact it works even better:

```
a.margins(0, 0)
```

Comment: I cannot do that before 2 days